# How do I serve files as a zip?

Tags: http, go, zip

I'm having a problem serving files for download over HTTP. With my current code, I can download one file easily.

```
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("TEST.docx")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3001", http.HandlerFunc(func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        rw.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.docx")
        http.ServeContent(rw, r, "test.docx", time.Now(), bytes.NewReader(data))
    })))
```

But I want to be able to download multiple files with one request. Something like this:

```
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("test.docx")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    data2, err := ioutil.ReadFile("test2.docx")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3001", http.HandlerFunc(func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        writer := zip.NewWriter(rw)
        create, _ := writer.Create("test.zip")
        _, _ = create.Write(data)
        _, _ = create.Write(data2)
        rw.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.zip")

        http.ServeContent(rw, r, "test.zip", time.Now(), /*What am I going to put here?*/)
```

How can I download these files as a zip? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're writing directly to the `ResponseWriter`, don't also use `http.ServeContent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood some of the concepts in my code but I fixed it. Now it works. This is the working code:

```
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("test.docx")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    data2, err := ioutil.ReadFile("test2.docx")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3001", http.HandlerFunc(func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
        writer := zip.NewWriter(buf)

        test, _ := writer.Create("test.docx")
        _, _ = test.Write(data)
        test2, _ := writer.Create("test2.docx")
        _, _ = test2.Write(data2)
        rw.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.zip")
        rw.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/zip")
        _ = writer.Close()

        http.ServeContent(rw, r, "test.zip", time.Now(), bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes()))
    })))
```

Comment: When I use just `buf`, Goland gives me this error: Cannot use 'buf' (type *bytes.Buffer) as type io.ReadSeeker Type does not implement 'io.ReadSeeker' as some methods are missing: Seek(offset int64, whence int) (int64, error).  Thats why I used this way.

Comment: Oh :/  Strange that it doesn't support that.

Comment: Your answer the only one that helped me to solve the same problem. Very clear and simple for such cases, when you try to create zip files on the fly. Big thanks.